# A question about the remainder of a Taylor Polynomial.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

1) Is the remainder you get $R_{n}(x)$ 
 = $f(x)$ - $P_{n}$(x) or is $R_{n}(x)$ just an approximation for the error?

2) Is $R_{n}(x)$ =$\frac{f^{n+1}(x^*)(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$  the rest of the Taylor series from the $(n+1)^{th}$ term with the new variable $x^*$? If so how come it's just one term if it contains the remainder of the Taylor series?

3) Why do you have to pick $x^*$ so that $R_{n}(x)$  will have the biggest error?

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: I don't understand the question (3).

Comment: This is just a matter of notation, but the $f^{n+1}(x^*)$ in 2) is often written as $f^{n+1}(\xi)$ to not have the ambiguity of $x^*$ potentially being a point which can be found. Here, $\xi$ is a point which we do _not_ know the value of, and is impossible to find. It is simply a statement of existence, that there is a value $\xi$ for the remainder, but we can not solve for it.

Comment: 3) Because that's the maximum error. You're trying to put an upper bound on the error. That's the point of everything else.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir, the error *is*... **the** error $f(x) - P_n(x)$. Any upper *bound* of the error will be... greater.

Comment: @Martin What? I'm responding to (3) -- to find an upper bound, you find the $x^*$ that maximises the expression you find for the error. This is what the OP is referring to.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir, really *bad* form of find an upper bound of the error. Usually the only information required of $x^*$ is the interval where lies.

Comment: @Martin I don't think you understood the OP's question (3). He's specifically asking why you would try to find the maximum value of the error. The answer is precisely "to find the upper bound".

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir, my first comment: "I don't understand the question (3)". "the maximum value of the error." is nonsensical. The error is *the* error. An upper bound of the error *isn't* "the maximum value of the error".

Comment: @Martin You're getting fixated on semantics. The maximum value of the expression in the question is the upper bound on the error. I'm not even sure what we're arguing about.

Comment: @AbhimanyuPallaviSudhir, first, there isn't *the* upper bound of error: there are an *infinite* number of upper bounds. Second, the maximum value of the expression *maybe doesn't exists*. Third, even if the the maximum of the expression exists, trying to find it is unnecessary. And using correctly the terminonology isn't "getting fixated on semantics".

Comment: Your argument is just -- "Why do we do X?" "To find Y." "But finding Y is unnecessary". What's necessary isn't the point, the question asked "why would you find the maximum of this expression?", and the answer is "for example, to put an upper bound on the error".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The remainder is by definition the error.

(2) $x^*$ is an *unknown* point. Isn't more mysterious than the unknown point in the Lagrange's mean value theorem. If what worries you is the *size* ("how come it's just one term if it contains the remainder of the Taylor series"), don't worry. Being the sum of many things $\ne$ being big.

Comment: So, $R_{n}(x)$ is the remainder of the Taylor series but is defined to be  $R_{n}(x)=$$\frac{f^{n+1}(x^*)(x-c)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$ by Taylor's therom. Is this correct?

Comment: @RoryShaughnessy, $R_n(x)$ *defined* as $f(x) - P_n(x)$. The different rest formulas *aren't* definitions.